# Resolved - M2: user creation fails with "class does not exit"

Tags: magento2, eav, eav-attributes

Magento 2 site, that had data transferred from a Magento 1.9 site.

When attempting to create a user, it fails with:

> Class Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Datetime does not exist

There are no entries that look like that in the `eav_attribute` table.

Is it looking for an `eav_attribute` in that table that isn't there? or is there an entry in another eav table that is making it look for a class somewhere?

**Solution:**

The migration had brought over some customer eav attributes from a HORRIBLE module (FME Booking and Reservation).  It was probably my fault for not mapping things correctly, however the solution was to delete the entries from the table `customer_eav_attribute`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm..., You're config class-map incorrectly when migrate Magento 1 to Magento 2. 
You should be checked this attribute_code in Magento 1 and change it to:

```
    <rename>
        <from>eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime</from>
        <to>Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Datetime</to>
    </rename>
    <!-- OR -->
    <rename>
        <from>eav/entity_attribute_frontend_datetime</from>
        <to>Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\Datetime</to>
    </rename>
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. As a last resort I will try the migration again.

Do you have any idea how to correct this without a new migration? I don't understand where/how it's looking for this class. I don't see it in the database or anywhere in the code.

Comment: You can see it on `class-map.xml` files